# Define HAS_XXX / NO_XXX for supporting / no-supporting a feature

Tags: c++, c, boost, c-preprocessor

Why do Boost C++11 developers prefer NO_XXX to HAS_XXX? As you can see, BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS is used in \boost\core\noncopyable.hpp,

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS)
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
      noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
#else
  private:  // emphasize the following members are private
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& );
      noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& );
#endif
```

If they selected BOOST_HAS_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS, things do not change,

```
#if defined(BOOST_HAS_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS)
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
      noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
#else
  private:  // emphasize the following members are private
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& );
      noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& );
#endif
```

Does using NO_XXX give us an advantage over using HAS_XXX?

Comment: You have to choose one or the other and not mix them.  The auto-tools (`autoconf` etc) use `HAS`; Boost may have chosen the alternative to distinguish themeselves from the the auto-tools.

Comment: You'd probably have to ask the person who named `BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS`. All anyone else can do is speculate and give opinions. (I could not find a naming conventions rationale on the Boost website that covers that name in particular.)

Answer (score 1):

An undefined "has" means (a) you have detected the feature is missing, or (b) you forgot to run the code that detects if the feature is missing.

You then write code that does/does not depend on the feature; the build succeeds in all 4 cases (feature there/not, detect code run/not).  But in 1 of the 4 cases (feature is there, detection code skipped) the wrong code is compiled.

An undefined "no" means (a) you have detected the feature exists, or (b) you forgot to run the code that detects if the feature is missing,

You then write code that does/does not depends on the feature.  The build fails when you forgot to run the feature detecting code, and you the feature is not there.

So `NO` is subject to 1 fewer silent error case, and has 1 more hard error that detects a program logic error statically.

Seems like a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

There actually *is* some difference – not in final output, but in the *default* setting:

- With `HAS_XXX` semantics, you need to explicitly enable a feature if you want to have it, default is the feature being turned off.
- with `NO_XXX` semantics exactly invers, default is on, but you can explicitly disable it (e. g. because of your compiler not supporting it)